# declare multiple variables into a variable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do i put multiple variables into one variable so that i can minify the code usage. How do i declare its so that i can use $scope.bundle instead of these 3 variables : $scope.acc.city, $scope.acc.state and $scope.acc.country. It is like a global variable that carry multiple variables so that i can use it everywhere without need to write the variables again and again.

The way i want to be is like this :

```
$scope.bundle = [{$scope.acc.city, $scope.acc.state, $scope.acc.country}]; 

$scope.postcode = resp.content;
if ($scope.postcode.length > 0) {
   $scope.bundle = $scope.postcode[0];
   $scope.acc = $scope.bundle;
} else {
   $scope.bundle = '';
   $scope.acc = $scope.bundle;
}
```

instead of :

```
if ($scope.postcode.length > 0) {
   var data = $scope.postcode[0];
   $scope.acc.city = data.city;
   $scope.acc.state = data.state;
   $scope.acc.country = data.country;
} else {
   $scope.acc.city = '';
   $scope.acc.state = '';
   $scope.acc.country = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an array of **objects**, so you need to provide `keys` for your `values`

```
$scope.bundle = [
   {
       city    : $scope.acc.city, 
       state   : $scope.acc.state, 
       country : $scope.acc.country
   }
];
```

Then you can access it like

```
$scope.bundle[0].city
```

---

If you've only got 1 item (instead of an array) you can create the object directly

```
$scope.bundle = {
    city    : $scope.acc.city, 
    state   : $scope.acc.state, 
    country : $scope.acc.country
};
```

Then you can access it without the `index` property

```
 $scope.bundle.city
```